# how to set date while type ="date".in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to set date .I used .val() function but it not work in android.

```
<input name="caseDate" id="caseDate"  min="2000-01-01" value="" type="date"  class="caseDate_h" >
```

**JS:**

```
 var now = new Date();
 var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
 var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
 var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
 var now = new Date();
 var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
 var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
 var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
 $('#caseDate').val(today); 
 $("#caseDate").attr("value", today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var now = new Date();

    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    var now = new Date();

    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

    $('#caseDate').val(today); 
    $("#caseDate").attr("value", today);
});
```

**Ourput**

2013-08-26

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code `$(document).on('pageinit', function {});`. This [jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events) might be helpful.

Comment: is there any event of pop up screen .Actually I am getting alert date .But But it not set

Comment: are you able to see the popup screen? perhaps the popup screen does not contain `<input name=caseDate>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the date into the format of "yyyy-mm-dd"

```
var todaysDate  = new Date();
var month = parseInt(todaysDate.getMonth() / 10) <= 0 ? "0" + todaysDate.getMonth() : todaysDate.getMonth();
var date = parseInt(todaysDate.getDate() / 10) <= 0 ? "0" + todaysDate.getDate() : todaysDate.getDate();
console.log(month);
console.log(date)
var today = todaysDate.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + date;
console.log(today);
$('#caseDate').val(today);
```

This should work.