# Change date in input type date HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem. I want to change the date in the input field to the current date. Here is my code:

```
<input type="date" id="datum currentdate">
```

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $('#currentdate').val(today);
});
```

But this doesn't work. I have included jQuery. Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: What means "But this doesn't work."?

Comment: It includes tt.mm.jjjj.

Comment: This is the standart of type="date"

Comment: you have invalid id, id have to be one unique word

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3v460p6n/1/

Comment: See link may be help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441181/how-to-set-date-while-type-date-in-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096442/javascript-date-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the id for your input field must be `currentdate` nor `datum currentdate`

```
<input type="date" id="currentdate">
```

Comment: But i need the other id for something else in my code....

Comment: @Micha then you can change the id of the field and in your jquery. But do not use blanks in the id.

Comment: Now it works. :D I just made it with a class not with an ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="currentdate" name="date">

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('currentdate').value = Date();
</script>
```

Comment: I think adding some explanation would make the answer better. thanks